# ImageURL doesn't work inside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, captcha

I am writing a captcha authentication program in ASP.NET C#. The problem i face is that the image gets refreshed on entering wrong value during a postback; but same image doesn't get refreshed during a partial postback, when i keep them inside an update panel.

**aspx source**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>            
            <asp:Image ID="ImageCaptcha" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/BringImg.aspx" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />                        
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Project"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private System.Random rand = new System.Random();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Session["Captcha"] = GenerateRandomCode();
        }
    }
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = this.Session["Captcha"].ToString();
        if (string.Compare(temp, this.txtCaptcha.Text.Trim()) == 0)
        {            
            // success logic
        }
        else
        {                     
            this.lblResult.Text = "Validation Text was not correct.";
            this.Session["Captcha"] = GenerateRandomCode();
            ImageCaptcha.ImageUrl = "~/BringImg.aspx";
            ImageCaptcha.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Frankly if you can avoid it, I would recommend against ASP.NET AJAX and use *real* AJAX instead.

Comment: Are you sending any no-cache headers? Is internet explorer set to get a new version of the page automatically? If so, set it to "Every Time I Visit The Webpage" under Tools-Options, "Browsing History->Settings"

Comment: I'd suggest you set the ajax nocache option which is this: $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your ~/BringImg.aspx page is setting it's content type to an image and generating your captcha image based off that session value.  The image likely isn't updating during partial postback because the browser doesn't realize that the image content has changed.  There are several ways to let the browser know the image has changed but one of the easiest to test is to apply a meaningless querystring (different for each image) to the ImageUrl of the captcha.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = this.Session["Captcha"].ToString();
    if (string.Compare(temp, this.txtCaptcha.Text.Trim()) == 0)
    {            
        // success logic
    }
    else
    {                     
        this.lblResult.Text = "Validation Text was not correct.";
        this.Session["Captcha"] = GenerateRandomCode();
        ImageCaptcha.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/BringImg.aspx?refresh={0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        ImageCaptcha.DataBind(); //This isn't necessary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with commenty above from @Aren . I have worked with update panels for 4 years and seen it doing all weired stuff sometimes . Use Jquery ajax rather which u can see transparently whats happened and IMO its really faster too.

This sounds like a caching issue. Make sure the end image has a random value to url . that way it will not use a cached version of image. Use firebug to see the GET request in Net panel and see if its dowloading latest image or not.

Not sure What does it mean at this line . What will be imageurl set to after execution .

```
ImageCaptcha.ImageUrl = "~/BringImg.aspx";
```

Comment: I was working with UpdatePanels for a while and felt that they were more hassle than they were worth. You have to do far too many work arounds to get something working as you want it.

Comment: @Sonesh This can be a caching problem as the captcha content gets changed (checked it through codes) but the image is not changed accordingly. i.e. even if i enter right content as shown in captcha, it says wrong value. The value gets changed if i apply a full postback. how to retrieve the image inside update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting update panel update mode to "Conditional"
and update the update panel after binding the captcha.

```
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Hope this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use recaptcha? 
I guarantee its a better solution and its free. http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

Your code above uses two different values in session - is this intentional or a source of your issue?:

Captcha and CaptchaImageTest

Comment: It was a typo. The session variables are same i.e. Captcha

Comment: I don't want the page to perform a postback when user enters wrong captcha value & gets another chance. I want the postback to happen only after user enters the right captcha value. Can this be achieved by recaptcha?

Comment: have you ruled out a cache issue? use fiddler and inspect the data coming back. does it contain the new image tag?

Comment: Arent you doing that now? either way you are doing a postback.

Comment: Nope, I am doing a partial postback not a full postback.

Comment: a post post is a post. The code behind doesn't matter - its still a post. with that in mind.. please describe what you want. you want a partial postback to occur, and the code validated correct? in that case absolutely you can do this with recaptcha.

Comment: Well there is a diff bet partial & full postback.... Take it as this way: I do not want other parts of the page to be refreshed or loaded again other than this captcha part.

Comment: from the client side yes, but in a btnClick event it doesnt matter. A post is a post unless you are specifically checking ajax headers or doing something different. in your case, you arent. What you want to do is indeed possible with recaptcha.

Comment: Here is a link in case it helps to have recaptcha with UpdatPanel .http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/test/UpdatePanel.aspx?r=121

Comment: Any eg with server side checking?

Comment: I saw one more post where recaptcha wont work with updatepanel.Did you try solution I said in my question ? I had similar issue where image wasnt getting updated cause of cache.I had to appened example.jpg?rand=435345 every time I wanted to update image.Using firebug for this kind of things is best solution to see whats happening.