# File Upload doesn't work in a page with Ajax Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, captcha, asyncfileupload

I am using Ajax File Upload control in ASP.NET 4 using c#. The same page has an update panel too but the upload control is not inside the update panel. The upload control is outside of the update panel.

The update panel has a captcha image and submit button which is [described here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259587/imageurl-doesnt-work-inside-update-panel). The submit button inside contains code for saving the file from upload control.

The problem is that when user has browsed the fife to be uploaded using upload control and then enters a wrong captcha value and submits, then a new captcha image is given asynchronously to the user for entry. Now the upload control still shows the path in the upload bar for the file, but on the programming side it does not detects the file.

The submit button code:

```
if (AsyncFileUpload.HasFile)
{
  // upload logic and other stuff
}
else
{
  // lblShow.Text = "There is no file to be uploaded";
}
```

The above code for example executes the else part to say "There is no file to be uploaded". The page still hasn't refreshed totally and the file upload control has the path of the file displayed. Kindly help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code:

```
if (AsyncFileUpload.HasFile)
{
  // upload logic and other stuff
}
else
{
  // lblShow.Text = "There is no file to be uploaded";
}
```

is in the `Page_Load` event, it will still execute in the context of a partial post-back, e.g. the `UpdatePanel` refresh.  If a full form submit has not been performed from the browser (you mentioned your File Upload is outside of the `UpdatePanel`) then the page will not detect the file upload.

What I am confused about is why you have called it `AsyncFileUpload` when it is outside the `UpdatePanel`?

**EDIT:**

Based on your answer, I don't think your Captcha implementation is workable with async file upload as you have it now.

The UpdatePanel does an async POST to evaluate captcha result, but you will not POST the file contents yet because its not inside the UpdatePanel.  Then your server-side code evaluates the captcha result and will either return html or a redirect in the async-response back to the browser... somewhere you need to eventually submit the form to get the file.

Unless you're prepared to write code to send some javascript back to your page in the async-response to trigger a full form submit, AND re-evaluate CAPTCHA again on the form submit, you're probably better off taking out the `UpdatePanel`, in my opinion.

Comment: The code is not inside page load event. Its inside the submit button's code. The captcha image, lblShow and submit buttons are inside update panel. The AsyncFileUpload is the Ajax File Uploader control which i m using from the Ajax Toolbox.

Comment: I wanted to get a functionality such as the user would have to upload the file only once as it is a heavy one and then if he enters a wrong captcha value, he can rectify it asynchronously. This way the user will not have to upload the file again the next time he enters a catcha value. Removing the update panel would do but then if users enters a wrong captcha and and the pages refreshes for another captcha try then the user will again have to upload the entire file from the control. Isn't there a workaround to do this asynchronously??

Comment: There are definitely ways to do it asynchronously. You could look into using an AJAX file upload component. (I believe many effectively use an iframe. HTML5 gives you more options, but not as widely supported)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax update panel with file upload control then you have to add postback trigger into update panel triggers. Like:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnContactSubmit"/>                                                         
</Triggers>
```

Comment: The partial postback happens quite fine even on adding or subtracting the postbacktrigger. The problem what exists here is I am losing the FileUpload's file which I am saving in the submit button code....